# Is there a way to hide imagery in gmail for a html responsive email build?

Tags: html, email, gmail, html-email

I'm building an email that has to have images hidden on the desktop and shown on the mobile. Only way you can do this is using display none which isn't supported by gmail.

I was wondering if there is any other ways of hiding images on the desktop version so that i can use media queries to style the email in the mobile version.

The problem is only in gmail

Much thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline style for desktop:

```
style="max-height:0;width:0;"
```

Responsive css @media query:

```
max-height: none !important;
width: auto !important;
```

Works like charm :)

Comment: clever! Worked nicely!

Answer (score 4):

On your inline styles for desktop, make the `width` and `height` of the image `0`. Then use your responsive media-query CSS to restore the image to its proper size.

Edit: Try adding `mso-hide:all;` to your inline css as well to fix issues with Outlook.

Comment: I'm afraid I have already tried this and it alot of email clients it will still explode the image regardless of its height and width. Which is a shame. Do you know any other ways of doing this? Thanks

Comment: I have used this method reliably before. Image and table cell holding it were set to width of 0.

I just checked my code, and I did also use "mso-hide:all;" on the table cell.

Comment: Nice thinking. Also found a post linked to what your talking about for others that are in need of a need to do the same.https://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/topic/7405/how-to-hide-mobile-content-in-desktop-clients/

Answer (score 1):

In order to hide an element in an HTML email and have it work in Gmail you need to zero it out and adjust the sizing in your CSS (which Gmail will ignore).

Like so:

```
<style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
    *[class~=show_on_mobile] {
        display : block !important;
        width : auto !important;
        max-height: inherit !important;
        overflow : visible !important;
        float : none !important;
    }
</style>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
        <td style="width: 0; max-height: 0; overflow: hidden; float: left;">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</table>
```

Additionally, the added conditional comment covers you for Outlook 07.

Answer (score 0):

`hidden` isn't a valid value for `display`.

Try:

```
{
    display:none;
}
```

Or, if that still doesn't work, try:

```
{
    visibility:hidden;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Oh Sorry.. I meant display none doesn't work on Gmail. And visibility is supported in even less clients.. Really can't see a work around this one other than don't do it..